# Should this have been marked as a duplicate

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

I answered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35312660/regex-search-not-working/35312759#35312759), which has now been closed by a gold tag badge as a duplicate.

The original question is more of less, *why is this regex not working?* and the "duplicate" question is a community wiki listing most of the regex syntax along with various online resources for regex.

Should this have been closed?  I can understand where the closer is coming from to a degree, but, at least when I was learning regex, pointing me to a list of regex characters would not have helped me understand what I was doing wrong?

Additionally, the closer says that my answer (the orignal version which has now been modified by a suggested edit from the OP) is not an answer as I merely explained why the OP's regex was not working.  As that was the question, I feel that it was an answer.

I'd like to know the community's' opinion on this, as my understanding is that this really isn't a duplicate.  Should this have been closed?

Comment: If you see a `regex` tag, don't answer but run. It is a tag that almost exclusively attracts _"gimme teh codez"_ questions, which most of the regular users loathe. It is an easy tag to score some reputation, but it's hardly ever useful for anyone but the OP.

Comment: Indeed.  If I started opening regex questions, I'm guessing I would soon be suspended again for umm.. 'unhelpful' comments and custom close-reasons.

Comment: @MartinJames: Yes, which proves there's something worse than PHP ;-)

Comment: What's the problem with closing it? It's still available for viewing and you still got your imaginary internet points. It's not deleted, which would remove both of those (although still viewable by users with 10k+ rep).